# Commit Maven assembly from Jenkins workspace to SVN

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, pom.xml

I want to know if there is a way to creat a **Job inJenkins** that commits a ***Maven assembly archive*** containinig sensitive data that i dont want to share in Nexus, generated with this ***Maven Goal***

```
-X -Pprod clean install
```

in

```
Jenkins-Workspace/project/target/archive-prod.tar.gz
```

to My ***SVN repository*** like this

```
    |branches
    |trunk
    |tags
       |project-version
       |project-config-version
           |archive-prod.tar.gz
```

Thank you

Comment: Sorry but I simply don't understand what you like to do and/or what kind of problem you are trying to solve? But If I understand something is: You would like to build a tar.gz and commit that within SVN? If this is correct I would say you are doing something wrong? Or please explain why you like to do this?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. However, I'm wondering why you would want to do this instead of publishing that artifact to a repo manager such as Nexus.

Comment: I updated the question , so i have already a job who puts a realease in Nexus (pom.xml + war file) . And i want to create a job that commits my generated archive ( sensitive data) to my repository

Comment: Than I ask again why would you like to put your archives into a version control system instead of an repository manager like Nexus/Artifactory which is exactly intended for such things in contradiction to your version control system? What kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: SVN repository is private (my-entity) and Nexus is public (all-entities) , so sensitive data like application.properties etc.. should be archived and stored only in a myrepo/tags/appVersion-config... As I said in the question Nexus should contain only war + pom.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re sure you really want this, I’m not sure there’s a plugin for it, but you can script it.

Add a shell step to the build that does the command line operations with the svn command. Make sure that the svn command on the desired agent has the credential and the access right to commit the files.

If your job is a Maven style job you will need a post build step. But even better, just make a new Freestyle job where the Maven part is just a regular step and add the new shell step.